# Strange layout gap in Chrome, IE7

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Hope someone can have a look and say why there's a horizontal gap on the land page of http://www.epickayaks.org/. It appears between Featured Slider and Main Content.Currently i experience it in Chrome 15, IE7(not IE8). OK in FF8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 388, you have this:

```
</script>?<!-- SUB POST DIVISIONS -->
```

Where that `?` is, there's a [UTF-8 byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (`ef bb bf`). Remove it and the gap is gone.

Comment: I'm not able to see that mark. I'm using notpad++

Comment: Are you using includes of some kind? You might need to save the file without the UTF-8 BOM (look in the "Encoding" menu).

Comment: yes. Had to manually walk all files and convert to utf w/o bom. worked

Answer (score 0):

The javascript code above this `<!-- SUB POST DIVISIONS -->` is generating an empty row. Remove it to test.